# Getting "AssertionError("Unknown application type")" when Connecting to DSE 5.1.0 Spark

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am connecting to DSE (Spark) using this:

```
new SparkConf()
  .setAppName(name)
  .setMaster("spark://localhost:7077")
```

With `DSE 5.0.8` works fine (`Spark 1.6.3`) but now fails with `DSE 5.1.0` getting this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Unknown application type
at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.DseSparkMaster.registerApplication(DseSparkMaster.scala:88) ~[dse-spark-5.1.0.jar:2.0.2.6]
```

After checking the use-spark jar, I've come up with this:

```
if(rpcendpointref instanceof DseAppProxy)
```

And within spark, seems to be RpcEndpointRef (NettyRpcEndpointRef).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and fixed it by following this:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkRemoteCommands.html

Then you need to run your job using `dse spark-submit`, without specifying any master.

Comment: Thanks @mikael. My app is not packaged and sent to DSE, I 'm running and app that connects directly to the spark cluster, using SparkConf.setJars for distributing. And probably that cannot be done with Dse 5.1. And that means dse-5.1.0 is not fully compatible with Apache Spark 2.0.2

Comment: @Johann did you find any solution?

Comment: @shiva.n404, Mikal was right. Let me know if you need some more help.

Comment: @Johann Did you find any description of this change of behaviour between DSE 5.0 and DSE 5.1 ? I can't seem to find any explanation about this on the website.

Comment: @Antoine, no I didn't. The only thing is they have implemented a spark-submit into their *dse* tool.

Answer (score 1):

#### Resource Manager Changes

The DSE Spark Resource manager is different than the OSS Spark Standalone Resource Manager. The DSE method uses a different uri "dse://" because under the hood it actually is performing a CQL based request. This has a number of benefits over the Spark RPC but as noted does not match some of the submission
mechanisms possible in OSS Spark.

There are several articles on this on the Datastax Blog as well as documentation notes

[Network Security with DSE 5.1 Spark Resource Manager](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dse-5-1-resource-manager-part-1-network-connections-security)

[Process Security with DSE 5.1 Spark Resource Manager](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dse-5-1-resource-manager-process-security)

[Instructions on the URL Change](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/startingSpark.html#startingSpark__specifying-spark-urls)

#### Programmatic Spark Jobs

While it is still possible to launch an application using "setJars" you must also add the DSE specific jars and config options to talk with the resource manager. In DSE 5.1.3+ there is a class provided
`DseConfiguration`
Which can be applied to your Spark Conf `DseConfiguration.enableDseSupport(conf)` (or invoked via implicit) which will set these options for you.

[Example](https://github.com/RussellSpitzer/ProgrammaticSparkExample/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/example/WriteRead.scala)

[Docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/compatibilitySparkSession.html?hl=accessing%2Cspark%2Csession%2Ccontext%2Capplications%2Crunning%2Coutside%2Cdse%2Canalytics)

This is of course for advanced users only and we strongly recommend using `dse spark-submit` if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

First of all, I think is impossible to run a Spark job within an Application within DSE 5.1. Has to be sent with `dse spark-submit`

Once sent, it works perfectly. In order to do the communications to the job I used Apache Kafka.

If you don't want to use a job, you can always go back to a Apache Spark.